# Find the inverse of an equation reminiscent of Kepler's equation

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

**Context**

For an eccentricity, $e$, Kepler's Equation is given as
\begin{align*}
M 
&=
  E  
- e\, \sin {\left(E\right)}   
\end{align*}
For a historical treatment of Kepler's equation and how to invert it, see [1] and references therein.

**Question**

Let $E$ be such that $E = [-\pi, \pi]$ and $M$ be such that $M = [-\pi, \pi]$. I have a form reminiscent of Kepler's Equation, which is 
\begin{align*}
M 
&=E -  \,
  \sin{\left( E \right)} \,   \left(- \dfrac{2}{3   } \,\cos^2{\left(\dfrac{E}{2}\right)}  - 1\right)
\end{align*}
How can I invert the above to find E(M)?

**Bibliography**

[1] Colwell, P. Solving Kepler's Equation over Three Centuries. Richmond, VA: Willmann-Bell, 1993.

Comment: There does not seem to be a closed form solution. But if $E$ is small, you can use the Taylor expansion $M \approx E + \frac{2}{5}E^5 + E^6  +O(E^7)$ to find an approximate solution quickly.

Comment: That series is incorrect.

Comment: @Robert Israel. Its a fair point that the the series might be incorrect. I've checked it and the series is correct.

Comment: No, it is not.  For one thing, you have an odd function of $E$, so that $E^6$ can't be there.  For another, the coefficient of $E^1$ should be $8/3$.

Comment: @Robert Israel. Its seems like you might have some important references regarding this material. Please put some citations to the material you are referring to.

Comment: @Hans Engler . Can you tell me how come you believe that there is no closed-form solution? I want to understand the basis for this assertion.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Indeed, I must have had a typo somewhere. Correct  is $\frac{8 E}{3}-\frac{4 E^3}{9}+\frac{E^5}{18} +O(E^7)$.

Comment: @MichaelLevy - there is no closed form solution of Kepler's equation. So no closed form can be expected for this related problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a closed form from:

> [Numerical inverse of a function: $\frac34 x - \frac 12\sin(2x) + \frac 1{16} \sin(4x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430330/numerical-inverse-of-a-function/4444881#4444881).

$$M=E -  \,
  \sin{\left( E \right)} \,   \left(- \dfrac{2}{3   } \,\cos^2{\left(\dfrac{E}{2}\right)}  - 1\right)\mathop\iff^{E=2\sin^{-1}(x)} M=2\sin^{-1}(x)+\frac23x(5-2x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Therefore we use $\int_0^x (1-t^2)^r=\frac12\text B_{x^2}\left(\frac12,r+1\right)$ with the [incomplete beta function $\text B_z(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=beta%28z%2Ca%2Cb%29), convert to [beta regularized $\text I_z(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=betaregularized%28z%2Ca%2Cb%29), and use the [haversine hav$(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=haversine)

$$M=\frac{16}3\int_0^{\sin\left(\frac E2\right)}(1-t^2)^\frac32dt=\frac83 \text B_{\sin^2\left(\frac E2\right)}\left(\frac12,\frac52\right)=\pi \text I_{\text{hav}(E)}\left(\frac12,\frac52\right) $$

Finally, we use [**inverse beta regularized $\text I^{-1}_s(a,b)$**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inversebetaregularized) and [inverse haversine hav$^{-1}(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+haversine):

$$\boxed{E=\text{hav}^{-1}\left(\text I^{-1}_{\frac M\pi -2n}\left(\frac12,\frac52\right)\right)+2\pi n, \text{hav}^{-1}\left(\text I^{-1}_{\frac M\pi -(2n+1) }\left(\frac52,\frac1
2\right)\right)+(2n+1)\pi,n\in\Bbb Z}$$

[**Shown**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inversehaversine%28inversebetaregularized%28%28x-sin%28x%29%28-2%2F3+cos%28x%2F2%29%5E2-1%29%29%2Fpi%2C1%2F2%2C5%2F2%29%29-x) is the $0\le M\le \pi$ case:

[image]

$\text I^{-1}_s\left(\frac52,\frac12\right)$ reduces the problem to a [student T distribution quantile](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=percentile+student+t+distribution+quantile+with+5+degrees+of+freedom) of $v=5$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: The linked post has a Fourier series

Answer (score 1):

There are different methods of proofs that the function of Kepler's equation doesn't have [partial inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) (over a complex domain without isolated points) that are [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

$$M=E-\sin(E)\left(-\frac{2}{3}\cos^2\left(\frac{E}{2}\right)-1\right)$$
$$E-\sin(E)\left(-\frac{2}{3}\cos^2\left(\frac{E}{2}\right)-1\right)-M$$
$$-\frac{1}{12}i(e^{iE})^4-\frac{2}{3}i(e^{iE})^3+(E-M)(e^{iE})^2+\frac{2}{3}ie^{iE}+\frac{1}{12}i=0$$
$E\to \frac{t}{I}$:
$$-\frac{1}{12}i(e^t)^4-\frac{2}{3}i(e^t)^3+(-M-it)(e^t)^2+\frac{2}{3}ie^t+\frac{1}{12}i=0$$

The function on the left-hand side of the latter equation is an algebraic function in dependence of both $t$ and $e^t$. Liouville proved that such kind of functions (over a complex domain without isolated points) don't have (partial) inverses that are elementary functions.

The equation is also an algebraic equation in dependence of both $t$
and $e^t$. Lin proved, assuming [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) is true, that such kind of equations don't have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

The latter equation also shows that the equation cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions and Lambert W or Generalized Lambert W either.

[How can we show that $A(z,e^z)$ and $A(\ln (z),z)$ have no elementary inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586412/how-can-we-show-that-az-ez-and-a-ln-z-z-have-no-elementary-inverse)